# Confusion regarding the nth term in a binomial expansion (positive integral index)

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

The expansion for a binomial is - $(a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}a^{n-k}b^{k} $

But it could also be this $(a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}a^kb^{n-k}$

Both of the expansions are correct because the pascal's triangle is palindromic, meaning that it doesn't matter whether we write the terms from the left end or from the right end. The first expression, which has $a^{n-k}$ is written from the left end, while the other one is written from the right end. The problem arises when I try to find the nth term in an arbitrary expansion $(a+b)^n$. For the first formula it comes out to be $T(r+1) = C(n,r) a^{n-r}b^r$

While in the second expansion the exponent of $a$ will be $k$, not $(n-k)$.
Now, in class, I was presented with a question to find the 5th term of some expansion. I used the second formula and returned with an incorrect answer, the correct one having come from the first formula. I tried asking my teacher, but I couldn't get a satisfactory response. Aren't such questions ambiguous? Shouldn't it be provided in the question whether we take the powers of $a$ in ascending or descending order? Or, if one term is negative, it would suffice to say whether the first term is positive or negative (if the index is odd). Should I just accept the first expression as convention? Any insight would be greatly appreciated as this has been troubling me for a while now. Thanks!

P.S. An example of such a problem is [image]

Comment: In the sum the order doesn’t matter. But I think convention is to place the highest powers of $a$ first. I. e. we write $(x+1)^2$ starting with $x^2$

Comment: So should i just accept this as convention? Take the example of (x+y)^3. This is x^3 + 3x^2y + 3xy^2 + y^3. This is also y^3 + 3xy^2 + 3x^2y + x^3. In the first, the second term is 3x^2y, but it the second it is 3xy^2. The coefficients will always be same due to the property of C(n,r) = C(n,n-r). Will the correct answer always be 3x^2y?

Comment: I would say yes. By convention.

Comment: Welcom to Math SE. It would really help if you post the math as text. This will help me, since I cannot see:)

Comment: @TobyHarnish I would love to but I don't know how to :(

Comment: If you just put a $ around math-like parts you will see the difference. Google will take you from there.

Comment: If you are asked for, say, the fifth term in some expansion, then it is incumbent upon the person asking you for it to tell you whether the fifth highest power of $a$ or the fifth lowest power is meant – otherwise, the question is ambiguous.

Comment: @ Gerry Myerson I see your point but how often do you see $(a+b)^n$ expansion starting with $b^n$ vs $a^n$? I would say both are right but one is certainly the dominant approach.

Comment: Here is information on formatting mathematics on this website: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference One way to write the Binomial Theorem is (a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}a^kb^{n-k} but with a dollar sign at each end of the expression (or double dollar signs at each end, if you want it as a display). Try it, and see!

Comment: @Robin, I'd feel very funny about writing $(1+x)^2=1+2x+x^2$ instead of $(1+x)^2=x^2+2x+1$. Or if I were asked to expand $(x+1)^{1/2}$ I'd certainly do it in increasing, not decreasing, powers of $x$. I'd agree that there are conventions, but which convention to use depends on context.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I agree with you completely. But unfortunately questions like the one I have provided in the post script are pretty common, and have only one correct option. I think I'll have to write it down to convention.

Comment: @TobyHarnish I've updated all the photos to text, hope you can see now :)

Comment: @Gerry Myerson I suppose I’m just saying that we order binomial terms in the way we like before expanding and there are customary ways. Which as you point out would be leading with the indeterminate when possible.